# How to Programatically get TFS Team Project Name

Tags: c#, tfs, checkin-policy

I am creating a check-in policy using:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
```

I want to get the current TFS Team Project Name from the current workspace or the PendingCheckin

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you want to use it?  A workspace and checkin can span projects ...

Comment: I am working on a check-in policy that copies any file currently being checked-in from the local developer workspace to a different location.  This location will be different based on which Team Project it belongs to

Comment: I didn't realize a check-in could scan multiple projects.  If it helps, I will always have a different workspace for each team project, but I could do this for each project if I could somehow get a list of all projects that the file is being checked-in to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [VersionControlServer.GetTeamProjectForServerPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.getteamprojectforserverpath.aspx) on a pending change thus:

```
var pendingChange = pendingCheckin.GetAllPendingChanges().FirstOrDefault();
if(pendingChange != null) {
    return vcs.GetTeamProjectForServerPath(pendingChange.ServerItem);
}
```

This also means you can detect if pending changes span multiple team projects.

---

Edit/expansion:

Now that I think about it, you should probably use the local path, since the files you're checking in might not be on the server yet (adds).

So you can use [Workspace.GetTeamProjectForLocalPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.getteamprojectforlocalpath.aspx) instead:

```
var workspace = pendingCheckin.GetWorkspace();
var pendingChange = pendingCheckin.GetAllPendingChanges().FirstOrDefault();
if(pendingChange != null) {
    return workspace.GetTeamProjectForLocalPath(pendingChange.LocalItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with

```
  BuildDetail.TeamProject
```

Find the assembly in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll

Comment: That's for a given build (which is related to a project).  I think he's asking given a workspace or pending checkin (which can span projects).

Comment: And I am not sure where to get the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.dll  It looks like I am missing that